# Javascript how to center an overlay when the user has zoomed in

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a iframe that I create and add to the page as an overlay. I want it to be in the center of the page. However, when I am on mobile on a non mobile optimized page, and zoomed in, the iframe usually shows up off the screen.

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;

display_width = 450;
margin = (width-450) / 2;

frame.setAttribute('style','z-index: 2147483647;position:fixed;top:20px;left:'+margin+'px;width:'+display_width+'px;margin:0px;border: 1px solid; border-color:#ddd;max-width:none;overflow:visible;');

function resizeFrameWidth(){
    var frame = document.getElementById('PennyPledge54DT');
    var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;

    var margin = 20;
    var display_width = width - 40;

    if(!mobile){
        display_width = 450;
        margin = (width-450) / 2;
    }
    frame.style.width = display_width+"px";
    frame.style.left = margin+"px";
}
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeFrameWidth);
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFrameWidth, true);
```

It works when I resize the window, but not when I zoom.

**edit:**
here is a jsfiddle as requested. However, the problem manifests itself when you zoom in on the content. I only know how to do that via a mobile device. So I don't know how useful a fiddle will be.

https://jsfiddle.net/41y62su7/

**edit**
Here's a screenshot of what my iframe looks like on mobile when I zoom in on the page a little bit.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example so we can easily modify and test this?

Comment: Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/41y62su7/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler method of achieving the same effect without grabbing the window.onresize event (which fires repeatedly throughout the resize event not just at the end). Using the heredoc function defined below allows for better maintainabilty and readability in your code. In this example I include the overlay which is not included in your javascript code.

This method uses margins to center the iframe within the overlay which is fixed in one position and set to the width and height of the viewport.

```js
function heredoc(f) {
  return f.toString().match(/\/\*\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*\*\//m)[1];
};
var overlay = document.createElement("div");
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.ca");
overlay.style.cssText = heredoc(function() {/*
  z-index: 2147483647;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
*/});
iframe.style.cssText = heredoc(function() {/*
  display: block;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow:visible;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
*/});
overlay.appendChild(iframe);
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(overlay);
// you can also use
// document.body.appendChild(overlay);
// if you don't want to require that the user have an element with the id main
```

```css
/* for example only, not required */
body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="main">
    This is a bunch of text. Yadda yadda.
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: I am actually making a plugin that other people will include on their site. So I want to do the whole thing with javascript because I won't be writing the html/css

Comment: It's not working on mobile. When I zoom in on the page I want it to stay centered. I've added a picture of what's happening.

Comment: I tried changing it to left:50vw but it's still not working the way I think it should when I zoom on mobile. If you click the green "pledge" button then it tries to display the overlay and you can see what I mean: http://universitylunchbox.com/blog.html

Comment: I guess I just have to deal with the problem then. Hopefully most people design their site to be optimized enough that it won't be too big of an issue.